# MapReduce with MongoDB. How can I store many results in one document?

Tags: mongodb

another MongoDB question.
I have a collection with documents that look like the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56ab6d594dfb5ab07e0b0c1b"),
    "docid" : 698,
    "term" : "xhtml",
    "score" : 0.033
}
```

For every `docid` there are multiple documents with a unique `docid/term` combination. For every term there is a score value.

What I want to achieve is to calculate the `average score` value for every `term`.

I tried this with MongoDB MapReduce.

My map function:

```
var map = function() {
    emit(this.term, this.score);
}
```

My reduce function:

```
var reduce = function(key, values) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        sum += parseFloat(values[i]);
    }
    var avg = sum/values.length;
    return avg;
}
```

The MapReduce finishes without errors but the output format is not how I expect it to be.

```
{ "_id" : NaN, "value" : 0.20074305555555552 }
{ "_id" : 0, "value" : 0.08428939198197966 }
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : 0.13808291796629674 }
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : 0.14154431740366513 }
{ "_id" : 3, "value" : 0.12549153892074566 }
{ "_id" : 4, "value" : 0.19003114590495843 }
{ "_id" : 5, "value" : 0.10077870909142886 }
{ "_id" : 6, "value" : 0.13208640358753815 }
{ "_id" : 7, "value" : 0.1474313158427689 }
{ "_id" : 8, "value" : 0.21607424755041157 }
{ "_id" : 9, "value" : 0.11993136619256084 }
{ "_id" : 10, "value" : 0.2146284765047667 }
```

<s>Problem is I don't understand why `_id` field contains numbers only. I thaught it will contain the emitted key value which was a string.</s>

Is it possible to create just one output document with all terms and their respective average scores like the document mentioned below?

```
{ <term1> : <AVG_SCORE>,
  <term2> : <AVG_SCORE>,
  ....
}
```

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: Why can't you use [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) for this task, it simplifies things a whole lot more than mapReduce?

Comment: Have to use it as preparation for the exam.

But i found out, that the "_id" field is correct. There are numeric values for terms in the collection.

So I'm only searching for a method to save all the <term> : <AVG_SCORE> pairs into one big document.